# Emit Socket Io send event from diffrent files with SvelteKit Websocket implementation

Tags: javascript, websocket, sveltekit

I have followed this tutorial
https://joyofcode.xyz/using-websockets-with-sveltekit
and implemented a basic websocket server that sends a message to the client when he connects.
I want to also send a message when someone submits a form.

```
// socketIo.ts.js
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
let io
export function injectSocketIO(server) {
    io = new Server(server);
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {     
      socket.emit('eventFromServer', 'Hello, World ')
    });
    
    console.log('SocketIO injected');
}

export function send(sms){
  io.emit('eventFromServer', sms);
}
export function getIO(){return io}
```

```
//vite.config.ts
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

import { injectSocketIO } from './socketIo.js';
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
const webSocketServer = {
  name: 'webSocketServer',
  configureServer(server) {
    injectSocketIO(server.httpServer);
  },
}


const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [sveltekit(), webSocketServer]
};

export default config;
```

```
//my form action

import { send } from './socketIo.ts'
export const actions = {
  default: async({ request }) =>{
    console.log(send('da'))
```

I'm getting this error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')
    at Module.send (/home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/socketIo.ts:17:5)
    at default (/home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/src/routes/+page.server.ts:10:16)
    at call_action (file:///home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/actions.js:204:9)
    at handle_action_request (file:///home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/actions.js:134:22)
    at render_page (file:///home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/index.js:65:26)
    at async resolve (file:///home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:247:17)
    at async respond (file:///home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:298:20)
    at async file:///home/runner/sveltekit-cpp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:418:22
```

I have tried exporting a send function from my socketIo file but it didn't work

Comment: Did you find a solution? We've encountered the same issue. Even using a linked module doesn't seem to solve the problem in Vite. (It does help for running the built code with adaptor-node)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:** your Socket.IO instance is attached to the Vite server, but your SvelteKit code can't access that server or its memory. So your SvelteKit server-side action tries to use an undefined SocketIO instance.

Your code would work with SvelteKit's "[adapter-node](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node)", though, if you [set up a custom web server](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#custom-server) to run both SocketIO and your SvelteKit routes.

1. Run `npm run build`.
2. Create a server.js file that spins up a web server (e.g. express).
3. Use that web server to set up your SocketIO (`injectSocketIO()`) and handle all the routes (using the `handler` generated by your SvelteKit build

However, you won't have socket support during development. (Vite server, not Node.)

**A solution for both dev/prod:**

Place all your pub/sub logic in a separate module outside SvelteKit, *including the server-side pub routes*.

Steps:

1. Set up your Socket.IO instance as before (`injectSocketIO()`) for both your Vite plugin (using `configureServer`) and your NodeJS `custom server` (as described above).
2. The Vite web server supports `express` middleware, write express middleware to handle your pub routes. Then, add the middleware in `configureServer`.
3. Important: to make sure your middleware handles the route instead of SvelteKit, define a proxy for your pub route.
4. Then, your client code can call your pub route instead of your form action (or via your form action).

Your `socketIo.ts.js` code will look something like this:

> ```
>     import express from 'express';
>     import { Server } from 'socket.io';
>     
>     let io;
>     
>     export function injectSocketIO(server) {
>         io = new Server(server);
>     
>         io.on('connection', (socket) => {     
>           socket.emit('eventFromServer', 'Hello, World ')
>         });
>         
>         console.log('SocketIO injected');
>     }
>     
>     const app = express();
>     
>     app.get('/api/pub', (req, res) => {
>       io.emit('eventFromServer', req.body);
>     })
>
>    const proxy = {
>      '/api/pub': {} //proxy our /api route to nowhere
>    };
>
>    export function expressPlugin() {
>       return {
>         name: 'express-plugin',
>          config() {
>             return {
>                server: { proxy },
>                preview: { proxy }
>             }
>          },
>         configureServer(server: ViteDevServer) {
>           injectSocketIO(server.httpServer);
>           server.middlewares.use(app)
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

Credit: Thanks to Rense Bakker for his [article about injecting middleware into Vite](https://dev.to/brense/vite-dev-server-adding-middleware-3mp5).